# gmaven plugin is giving object heap space error

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven-plugin

I am getting error due to gmaven-plugin and groovy is giving error saying that groovy classpath could not find enough object heap space.I am using 32 bit system & Intellij idea ide. I have tried various options but could not resolve it ?

What i have tried are :

```
<configuration>
  <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
</configuration>

Xmx256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
For 32 bit 
-Xms1336m -Xmx1336m

I Got the same error,and resolved this by configuring in the run.conf.bat
Run the JVM with the configuring run.conf.bat in Jboss5x
If free memory is not available AS you are passing in the statement then please make changes in run.conf.bat
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

<configuration>
    <maxmemory>1024M</maxmemory>
</configuration>

According to this IBM document about the Java heap size (along with some hints about setting the right heap size) the limits for Windows are:
•   maximum possible heap size on 32-bit Java: 1.8 GB
•   recommended heap size limit on 32-bit Java: 1.5 GB (or 1.8 GB with /3GB option)

MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

Could  anyone help me out in getting rid of this ?
```

Comment: Do you use the gmaven or the gmaven plus plugin?